# How is possible to set interline inside this block of code?

Tags: spacing, xetex, parskip

Have this code that generate an aside section:

```
\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\newenvironment{aside}{%
  \let\oldsection\section
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} ##1}
  }
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}
  \end{textblock}
  \let\section\oldsection
}
```

Works well but i want to increase the interline in the text inside `aside` section...

Have tried to insert after `\obeycr` command this line:

```
\par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
```

but change the interline between `aside` sections, not on text lines inside the sections.

This is the .tex source

```
\begin{aside}
  \section{info}
    Homer J. Simpson
    123 Fake Street
    Springfield, NJ 08105-442
    555-966-5786
    \href{mailto:homer@simpson.com}{homer@simpson.com}
\end{aside}
```

[image: and this is the output]

I need to increase interline between andress and phone number, and from phone number and email link.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would you please make this into a complete example? (Always pleased to see other Italians here. `:-)`)

Comment: @egreg Yes, the .tex source and an image of generated pdf is sufficient?

Comment: @egreg are know that are italian for my poor english, true? :D

Comment: No, you wrote it in your profile page! `:-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX can't know that you want a space before telephone numbers or email addresses, nor it can know that some characters form a telephone number or an email address. So either you use explicit spacing commands or mark the input in some way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\newenvironment{aside}{%
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}%
  \end{textblock}%
}
\providecommand\headingfont{} % I don't know what you want to define it
\definecolor{headercolor}{rgb}{0,0,1} % I don't know what's your favorite color

\newcommand{\tel}[1]{\addvspace{1ex}#1}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\addvspace{1ex}\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}

\newcommand{\asidesection}[1]{%
  \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #1}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{aside}
  \asidesection{info}
    Homer J. Simpson
    123 Fake Street
    Springfield, NJ 08105-442
    \tel{555-966-5786}
    \email{homer@simpson.com}
\end{aside}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I've used a different command for the title, since I would never redefine `\section` for that purpose. However this is a matter of tastes. Notice that `\let\oldsection\section` and `\let\section\oldsection` are superfluous, as your redefinition takes place inside an environment which forms a group.

If your `aside` environments all have a title, you can use a different strategy:

```
\newenvironment{aside}[1]{%
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
  \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor}#1}%
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}%
  \end{textblock}%
}
```

and your environment would be

```
\begin{aside}{info}
    Homer J. Simpson
    123 Fake Street
    Springfield, NJ 08105-442
    \tel{555-966-5786}
    \email{homer@simpson.com}
\end{aside}
```

[image]

Comment: @projetmbc Yes, you're right: switched two lines.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can do so manually, if that's an acceptable option:

[image]

Where `\par\medskip` could be replaced by `\par\smallskip` or `\\[3pt]` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\newenvironment{aside}{%
  \let\oldsection\section
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\color{blue} ##1}
  }
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)
  \begin{flushright}
}{%
  \end{flushright}
  \end{textblock}
  \let\section\oldsection
}

\begin{document}

\begin{aside}
  \section{info}\par
    Homer J. Simpson\par
    123 Fake Street\par
    Springfield, NJ 08105-442\par\medskip
    555-966-5786\par\medskip
    \href{mailto:homer@simpson.com}{homer@simpson.com}
\end{aside}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Uhm...works, but if find an automatic way is better, have too section inside `aside`

Comment: @byterussian TeX can't understand English or any other language; you *have* to mark the objects in some way or use an explicit spacing.

Comment: egreg has you covered :)